# How to get and use UIInterfaceOrientation items from info.plist?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, info.plist

I would like get the item0 of the supported interface orientations in my info.plist.

[image]

In order to have something like this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

     NSArray *supportedOrientations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];

     return supportedOrientations[0];
```

}

But of course I have an incompatibility type error:
`Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'id' from a function with result type`

How to solve this?

Comment: The entry in the info dictionary is likely a string. Have you tried making your own conversion function?

Answer (score 2):

As @Mats mentioned in his comment, the info dictionary contains string values for the supported orientations. You need to convert the string value to the desires `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` type. You may use a string category to do this.

**NSString+UIDeviceOrientation.h**

```
static NSString *kUIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait";
static NSString *kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft";
static NSString *kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight";
static NSString *kUIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown";

@interface NSString (UIDeviceOrientation)

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)deviceOrientation;

@end
```

**NSString+UIDeviceOrientation.m**

```
@implementation NSString (UIDeviceOrientation)

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)deviceOrientation {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if ([self isEqualToString:kUIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]) {
        mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else if ([self isEqualToString:kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]) {
        mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }
    else if ([self isEqualToString:kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]) {
        mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    else if ([self isEqualToString:kUIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown]) {
        mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    }

    return mask;
}
```

**Swift version**

```
extension String {
private var kUIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: String {
    return "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait"
}

private var kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: String {
    return "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft"
}

private var kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: String {
    return "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"
}

private var kUIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: String {
    return "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"
}

public var deviceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    switch self {
    case kUIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        return .portrait

    case kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        return .landscapeLeft

    case kUIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        return .landscapeRight

    case kUIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        return .portraitUpsideDown

    default:
        return .all
    }
}
}
```